# Using a function on a list of strings

Tags: haskell

```
f :: [String] -> String
f xs = minimum (filter (\e -> length e < 6 && isLower e) xs)
```

I would like the function `f` to find the smallest element in a list by checking if the length is less than six and all Chars in a string are lower case and if there are no strings that meet these requirements the function returns `"0"`.

```
f ["a","zz","ddDd","RRRR","ppppppp"] = "a"
```

When I compile my code I get the error

> `Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]`

Comment: Where's your code? Also `[Char]` is equivalent to `String`, so I don't see the issue here.

Comment: Take a look at `minimum`.

Comment: `isLower` works on a single `Char`, not on a `String`. You want to test if `all` the characters in the string are lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

will interest you.